# MVC: Get Intellisense in T4 Templates for own Controllers and function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, intellisense, t4

In T4 Templates, i can get Intellisense when typing `string.`

[image: string]

How can I get this support for my own controller and functions, e.g. typing `myClass.` doesnt work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I get intellisense in a T4 template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420766/how-can-i-get-intellisense-in-a-t4-template)

Comment: Well my question is more how to get intellisense for my own modules and not to get intellisense in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this editor gives me complete intellisense supprot in T4-Templates: Visulal T4: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/40a887aa-f3be-40ec-a85d-37044b239591

Same for the tangible T4 Editor, but only in the PRO Edition:
http://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get intellisense for the C# blocks in your template files.

https://github.com/kingces95/T4Isense/tree/master

Basically, it uses an `include` to pull in a `.cs` file that has been commented and #defined so that it can be included in a template but also parsed by VS to provide coloring and isense. It's simplest to clone the project and play with it to see how it works.

This approach does require all the C# be pulled out of the template into a `<#+ ... #>` block but the upside is the isense is provided by VS so it's as good as it gets.