# C# Templating engine with Intellisense support

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, templating

I'm looking for a templating engine to use in Visual Studio (C#) that supports Intellisense and syntax highlighting.
I haven't found anything...

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420766/how-can-i-get-intellisense-in-a-t4-template) answer helps..

Comment: Can you add more details? What kind of templates do you need? Something like T4 templates? Razor pages? The phrase "templating engine" is very broad.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Stack Overflow is not a programming nor a course service. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right

Comment: I need to generate strings from a template, mixing text and code...I think this work can be done by a "templating engine" like T4 templates (but not necessarly that one)

Comment: @PeterSchneider Thank you, I'll try "tangible T4 Editor"

Comment: Tangible should do what I ask, but the free version has limited intellisense. My only option is to buy the paid version and hope it does what I'm looking for.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really good cause for creating a fully C# compliant template engine, naturally Razor has been built but with a heavy footprint.

Try out RazorLite which supports .net standard and .net core. It is based on Razor and this is not so light weight but works pretty well.

https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight

Answer (score 0):

Probably this question is going to be downvoted because of site policies, but you could probably evaluate Microsoft's own [Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0) template engine, employed by Asp.Net. The tooling is very good, even when run from a compatible library, like [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) or similar related projects.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for, but this project seems abandoned

Comment: I tried it but it isn't compatible with latest .Net Core versions